# Action in Form is printing the file name rather than invoking the action's php file?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am very new to php programming and particularly in eclipse. I am having this problem that wasn't happening before.

My file is called index.php, I have only one file called, which is index.php, and I have this very simple code in it. Basically my code just call itself:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action='index.php'>
      <label>

  <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" />
  </label>
      <label>
      <input type="submit" name="submitcontent" id="submitcontent" value="extract files" />
      </label>
    </form>
```

When I run the code and click the submit button, instead of reloading index.php as I have put in the action request, the output is a white page with a string "index.php". I spent several hours trying to find the error with no hope.

Can you please advice what is my mistake,

What is keeping me wondering is if I run this code in dreamweaver, it works perfectly i.e. reloading the index.php as it is suppose to do.

Many thanks

**// EDIT: Here is the full code as requested..**

**In eclipse I use debug as PHP script. Does it matter ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>

<body class="twoColLiqLtHdr">

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action='index.php'>
      <label>
      <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" />
      </label>
      <label>
      <input type="submit" name="submitcontent" id="submitcontent" value="extract files" />
      </label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Dagon, I posted the full code that I am using. Also index.php is the only code, so I am calling the same file.

Comment: have you tested in a browser like, FF, IE, Chrome, etc.??

Comment: @tttony: I am running the debugger in eclipse and that's happening ... I am not sure what browser eclipse is using. But in dreamweaver, I am using Firefox and the code is working perfectly.

Comment: @tttony: I went and changed the browser at Prefrences->General->Webbrowser to IE and Firefox. Same problem still persists :(

Comment: if works in Firefox is fine, if you need to test in eclipse you have to configure eclipse properly to run php scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. So here are the mistakes I made:

1- My problem wasn't really with PHP or Eclipse but rather with the server. My debugger wasn't configured correctly.

2- I was debugging using PHP script and not PHP webpage. The former can debug without the need to connect to the server (just a script), while the latter debug the web page on the server.

Once I ensured that my debugger is setup correctly using php -m then setting PDT was a piece of cake.